# Cannot install pyDNS with Python 3. Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

I run python 3.6 and try to install the pyDNS package from pip. When I run `pip install pyDNS` or `pip3 install pyDNS` I get the error:

`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\USER\App Data\Local\Temp\pip-install-7r09f2ua\pyDNS\`

I've been trying to install the `setuptools` upgrade with the command `pip install --upgrade setuptools` but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pyDNS` is Python2-only. Try `py3dns` or `dnspython`:

```
pip install py3dns
pip install dnspython
```

Comment: but validate_email still searches for pydns. I get this: "Exception: For check the mx records or check if the email exists you must have installed pyDNS python package".

Comment: The question is about `PyDNS`, not `validate_email`. To replace `PyDNS` for Python 3 install and use `py3dns`. To use a different package with Python 3 install and use `dnspython`.